MediaLive Archive OutputGroup Object references undefined destination
In the console when you add an Archive OutputGroup, you are provided Archive group destination A section where you can paste the URL of the S3 bucket "s3://<bucket>/<folder>" The next section Archive settings you add the archive Name and the rollover interval.
The last section Archive outputs you can set the Name Modifier and you get default Audio and Video settings.
I am unable to create this using the java 2.x software.amazon.awssdk.
    private OutputGroup buildArchiveOutputGroup(String liveName, String mediaPackageChannelId) {
        log.info(LOG_FORMAT, liveName, mediaPackageChannelId);

        S3Uri s3Uri = s3Service.createArchiveFolder(liveName);
        String destinationUri = s3Uri.uri().toString();
        log.info(LOG_FORMAT + " S3 {}", liveName, mediaPackageChannelId, destinationUri);
        Output archiveOutput = Output.builder()
            .outputName("p4csa7")
            .outputSettings(outputSettings ->
                outputSettings
                    .archiveOutputSettings(archiveOutputSettings -> archiveOutputSettings
                        .nameModifier("_Live")
                        .containerSettings(archiveContainerSettings ->
                            archiveContainerSettings.m2tsSettings(m2tsSettings -> m2tsSettings
                                    .bufferModel(M2tsBufferModel.MULTIPLEX)
                                    .audioBufferModel(M2tsAudioBufferModel.ATSC)
                                    .rateMode(M2tsRateMode.CBR)
                                    .programNum(1)
                                    .segmentationMarkers(M2tsSegmentationMarkers.NONE)
                                    .segmentationStyle(M2tsSegmentationStyle.MAINTAIN_CADENCE)
                                    .ebpPlacement(M2tsEbpPlacement.VIDEO_AND_AUDIO_PIDS)
                                    .ebpAudioInterval(M2tsAudioInterval.VIDEO_INTERVAL)
                                    .audioStreamType(M2tsAudioStreamType.DVB)
                                    .absentInputAudioBehavior(M2tsAbsentInputAudioBehavior.ENCODE_SILENCE)
                                    .audioFramesPerPes(2)
                                    .esRateInPes(M2tsEsRateInPes.EXCLUDE)
                                    .ccDescriptor(M2tsCcDescriptor.DISABLED)
                                    .patInterval(100)
                                    .pmtPid("480")
                                    .pmtInterval(100)
                                    .videoPid("481")
                                    .pcrControl(M2tsPcrControl.PCR_EVERY_PES_PACKET)
                                    .pcrPeriod(40)
                                    .audioPids("482-498")
                                    .dvbTeletextPid("499")
                                    .dvbSubPids("460-479")
                                    .scte27Pids("450-479")
                                    .scte35Control(M2tsScte35Control.NONE)
                                    .scte35Pid("500")
                                    .klv(M2tsKlv.NONE)
                                    .klvDataPids("501")
                                    .timedMetadataBehavior(M2tsTimedMetadataBehavior.NO_PASSTHROUGH)
                                    .timedMetadataPid("502")
                                    .ebif(M2tsEbifControl.NONE)
                                    .etvPlatformPid("504")
                                    .etvSignalPid("505")
                                    .arib(M2tsArib.DISABLED)
                                    .aribCaptionsPidControl(M2tsAribCaptionsPidControl.AUTO)
                                    .aribCaptionsPid("507")
                                    .nielsenId3Behavior(M2tsNielsenId3Behavior.NO_PASSTHROUGH)
                                    .build())
                                .build())
                        .build())
                    .build())
            .videoDescriptionName("video_apmblz")
            .audioDescriptionNames("audio_fbtpg")
            .build();

        return OutputGroup.builder()
            .name("archive-s3")
            .outputGroupSettings(outputGroupSettings -> outputGroupSettings
                .archiveGroupSettings(archiveGroupSettings -> archiveGroupSettings
                    .rolloverInterval(300)
                    .destination(destination -> destination.destinationRefId(destinationUri))
                    .build())
                .build())
            .outputs(archiveOutput)
            .build();


Object references undefined destination "s3://<bucket>/<folder>" (Service: MediaLive, Status Code: 422, Request ID: fubar)
Has anyone successfully built the ArchiveGroupSettings with S3 destination?

Are you able to use pass the correlating Channel JSON from your AWS CLI?
This can be a good method for debugging any syntax error.
my reference example for S3 target url:
"Url": "s3://mybucket01/folder1/folder2/archive"
-- output files will be of the form 'archive_1_00001.ts'

I haven't been able to log the json simular to how I log the opensearch json. The URL is correct and matches the pattern for working channel set up via console. The issue is I am not setting the correct field, destination, which the console labels URL.
